# Printing kerning problem

Tags: printing, libreoffice

When I print from LibreOffice the kerning (inter-letter spacing) is awful with letters overlapping and spaces where there should not be any.

I have found that if I click Properties from the Print Dialog, then tell it to "print as" Postscript Level 3, instead of PDF, then this comes out fine.

I've set up the virtual PDF printer in CUPS and can repeat the problem (and workaround) printing to that, which means it's not to do with the specific driver for my printer.

So it could be **CUPS**, **Ghostscript**, or possibly LibreOffice. Does anyone know **where I should report this problem and which app is likely to blame**?

Here's some screenshots to show the problem (nb. some printed documents are a lot worse than these examples and quite unreadable, but I can't share those docs as they have sensitive info in)

[image: "Print as PDF"]

and how it should look

[image: "Print as PS L3"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was possibly a bug in LibreOffice 3.5; Install [LibreOffice 4](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/) and the problem goes away.